# Chart.js maxBarThickness is deprecated in angular 8

Tags: chart.js, angular8

I am facing issue of deprecated methods:

```
Chart.js:1990 bar chart: "scales.[x/y]Axes.maxBarThickness" is deprecated. Please use "dataset.maxBarThickness" instead
```

How this can be resolved?

I was using following way to set maxBarThickness of bar graph dynamically

```
this.barOptions.scales.xAxes[0]['barPercentage'] = 0.8;
```

But this is throwing warnings now.

Please share your suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This property is no longer part of the `xAxis` but it can be set directly on the `dataset` as explained in [dataset configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration).

Please also see [example usage](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#example-usage).

```
data: {
    datasets: [{
        barPercentage: 0.5,
        barThickness: 6,
        maxBarThickness: 8,
        minBarLength: 2,
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
    }]
};
```